# App Crash - Random Image Generator

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I am currently making a program that gets an array, sets it equal to a list of images, then uses a random number generator to display all these images. I'm running the apps on my physical Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge.

Code:

```
package com.binnieapplications.secondapp;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button doStuffButton;
    doStuffButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doStuffButton);

    final ImageView topAndroidImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.topAndroidImage);

    final ImageView bottomAndroidImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bottomAndroidImage);

   final int[] pictureArray = {
            R.drawable.dragonite,
            R.drawable.garchomp,
            R.drawable.gardevoir};



    doStuffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("RandomApp","Hello!");

            Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
            int number = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(6);
            Log.d("RandomApp", "The random number is: " + number);

            bottomAndroidImage.setImageResource(pictureArray[number]);
        }
    });


}
   }
```

I'm then getting this error and the app crashes:

```
02-05 18:36:03.329 22413-22413/com.binnieapplications.secondapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.binnieapplications.secondapp, PID: 22413
                                                                                  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=5
                                                                                      at com.binnieapplications.secondapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6213)
                                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11074)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23645)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: Thats because you are generating the range of [0,5] but you have only index till 2 as in 0,1,2 thats what the error is saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change you Random generator bound to 3 from 6 as your Picture array size is 3

```
int number = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(3);
```

nextInt(3) The method call returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and 3 (exclusive).